# MySQL issue if subquery is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, null, subquery, left-join

I have 5 tables (i'll talk only about what't in the request):

- Employee (login, agencyID)
- FreqTest (id, clientEmail, employeeLogin)
- QuestTest (id, clientEmail, employeeLogin)
- SitTest (id, clientEmail, employeeLogin)
- Client (email, age, gender)

Here is my request :

```
SELECT Client.email, Client.age, Client.gender
FROM Client,
  (SELECT FreqTest.clientEmail
  FROM FreqTest,
    (SELECT Employee.login
    FROM Employee
    WHERE Employee.agencyID = 'anID') EmployeeByAgency
  WHERE FreqTest.employeeLogin = EmployeeByAgency.login) Freq,

  (SELECT QuestTest.clientEmail
  FROM QuestTest,
    (SELECT Employee.login
    FROM Employee
    WHERE Employee.agencyID = 'anID') EmployeeByAgency
  WHERE QuestTest.employeeLogin = EmployeeByAgency.login) Quest,

  (SELECT SitTest.clientEmail
  FROM SitTest,
    (SELECT Employee.login
    FROM Employee
    WHERE Employee.agencyID = 'anID') EmployeeByAgency
  WHERE SitTest.employeeLogin = EmployeeByAgency.login) Sit

WHERE Client.email = Freq.emailClient
OR    Client.email = Quest.emailClient
OR    Client.email = Sit.emailClient
GROUP BY Client.email;
```

I want **emails** of any **Client** who had a **Test** in an **Agency**.
It works in almost any case, except if no Client had the 3 Tests in the same Agency.

I had to try to translate this in english and I am sorry if my english isn't perfect.

So just to be clear (with the same Agency):

- If Client**A** had a **FreqTest** and a **QuestTest**, Client**B** had the **3** and Client **C** had **none**, I get emails of **A** and **B**
- If Client**A** had **3** Tests, Client**B** **3** Tests as well and Client**C** had **none**, I still get emails of **A** and **B**
- If **no Client** had the **3** different Tests, no matter what I get nothing

I thought maybe it was because if any of the subqueries (Freq, Quest or Sit) returned no results it would be a NULL.

Again I would like to apologize if I'm not clear or if I made mistake translating all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LEFT JOIN to avoid NULL references

```
SELECT Client.email, Client.age, Client.gender
FROM Client
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT FreqTest.clientEmail
  FROM FreqTest,
    (SELECT Employee.login
    FROM Employee
    WHERE Employee.agencyID = 'anID') EmployeeByAgency
  WHERE FreqTest.employeeLogin = EmployeeByAgency.login) Freq
ON Client.email = Freq.emailClient

LEFT JOIN  (SELECT QuestTest.clientEmail
  FROM QuestTest,
    (SELECT Employee.login
    FROM Employee
    WHERE Employee.agencyID = 'anID') EmployeeByAgency
  WHERE QuestTest.employeeLogin = EmployeeByAgency.login) Quest
ON Client.email = Quest.emailClient

LEFT JOIN  (SELECT SitTest.clientEmail
  FROM SitTest,
    (SELECT Employee.login
    FROM Employee
    WHERE Employee.agencyID = 'anID') EmployeeByAgency
  WHERE SitTest.employeeLogin = EmployeeByAgency.login) Sit
ON  Client.email = Sit.emailClient
WHERE Freq.emailClient is NOT NULL
OR    Quest.emailClient IS NOT NULL
OR    Sit.emailClient IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Client.email;
```

Comment: Worked as expected, thank you. I feel sad for being clumsy handling NULLs.